# How to embed OpenEJB in existing Tomcat installation

Tags: java, tomcat, ejb, tomcat8, openejb

I have a current install of Tomcat 8. I'd like to add EJB support to it. But when I searched online for how to embed OpenEJB into Tomcat, I only found TomEE results and nothing about plain Tomcat. I'd prefer not to have a dedicated EJB server running, but to instead run the EJBs on the same JVM as Tomcat and my application. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The short answer is that you don't. You use TomEE or WildFly or one of the plethora of other Java EE implementations. Surely you have better things to do?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way to do that is just to download Apache TomEE, which nothing more than Tomcat with OpenEJB already embedded in it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add tomee webapp into your tomcat (through server.xml is fine), ensure you have tomee-loader in common.loader through catalina.properties and add in server.xml org.apache.tomee.loader.OpenEJBListener in the server.xml Listeners.